What is the probability that a run of n consecutive successes occurs before a run of m consecutive failures? Recursive approach
I'm working on this example from the book "A First Course in Probability" by Sheldon Ross. I tried to follow a recursive approach, because at fist I didn't get a step of the reasoning of author.
This is the problem:
Independent trials, each resulting in a success with probability $a$ or a failure with probability $b=1−a$, are performed. We are interested in computing the probability that a run of $n$ consecutive successes occurs and before a run of $m$ consecutive failures.
Solution
Let $f(n,m)$ be the probability of the event "a run of $n$ consecutive successes occurs and before a run of $m$ consecutive failures"

Conditioning on the outcome of the first trial we get
\[
f(n, m) = a\,f(n - 1, m) + b\,f(n, m - 1)
\]
The probability that we get one success before $k$ failures is
\[
f(1, k) = 1 - b^{k} \qquad k \geq 2
\]
The probability that we get $k$ successes before one failures is
\[
f(k, 1) = a^k \qquad k \geq 2
\]
We can use Pascal's triangle in order to write $f(n,m)$ a sum of terms of the form $f(1,k)$ and $f(k,1)$. Here is a diagram relative to the case $f(7,3)$:
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccc}
 &  &  &  &  &  &  & f(7,3)\\
 &  &  &  &  &  & f(6,3) &  & f(7,2)\\
 &  &  &  &  & f(5,3) &  & 2f(6,2) &  & \color{blue}{f(7,1)}\\
 &  &  &  & f(4,3) &  & 3f(5,2) &  & \color{blue}{2f(6,1)}\\
 &  &  & f(3,3) &  & 4f(4,2) &  & \color{blue}{3f(5,1)}\\
 &  & f(2,3) &  & 5f(3,2) &  & \color{blue}{4f(4,1)}\\
 & \color{red}{f(1,3)} &  & 6f(2,2) &  & \color{blue}{5f(3,1)}\\
 &  & \color{red}{6f(1,2)} &  & \color{blue}{6f(2,1)}
\end{array}
Adding the terms of the descending diagonal (in red) and the ones of the ascending diagonal  (in blue) we get the value of $f(7,3)$. It's not difficult to work out the general formula:
\[
f(n,m) = \color{red}{\underbrace{\color{black}{\sum_{k = 0}^{m - 2} \binom{n - 2 + k}{k}\,f(1, m - k)\,a^{n - 1}\,b^{k}}}} + \color{blue}{\underbrace{\color{black}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 2} \binom{n +m - 4 - k}{m - 2}\,f(2 + k, 1)\,a^{n - 2 - k}\,b^{m - 1}}}}
\]
Remembering the boundary conditions we get
\[
f(n,m) = \sum_{k = 0}^{m - 2} \binom{n - 2 + k}{k}\,(1 - b^{m - k})\,a^{n - 1}\,b^{k} +
\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 2} \binom{n + m -4 - k}{m - 2}\,a^{2 + k}\,a^{n - 2 - k}\,b^{m - 1}
\]
The formula derived by the author is
\[
f(n,m) = \dfrac{a^{n - 1}(1 - b^{m})}{a^{n - 1} + b^{m - 1} - a^{n - 1},b^{m - 1}}
\]
I tried to compare the values obtained by these formulas, but they don't match.
Moreover the author's formula doesn't satisfy the condition
\[
f(n,m) = a\,f(n-1,m) + b\,f(n,m-1)
\]
so I don't understend whether there's something wrong in my reasoning or the author's formula is wrong.

The problem is already in your equation
$$
f(n, m) = a\,f(n - 1, m) + b\,f(n, m - 1)\;.
$$
After a success (with probability $a$), $n-1$ successive successes only yield a total of $n$ successive successes if they occur right after the first success. So you can’t express $f(n,m)$ in that way.

$\underline{\text{Overview}}$
My response expands on the answer given by joriki.
Let $~f(n,m)~$ denote the probability that $~n~$ consecutive wins, occur before $~m~$ consecutive losses, where $~a~$ equals the probability of a win, and $~b = 1 - a.$
As I see it, there are $~(m + n - 1)~$ possible states:

You are just before the first trial. 
I will let $~f(n,m,0,0)~$ denote the probability of winning if you are in this state. 
So, $~f(n,m),~$ the value to be computed, equals $~f(n,m,0,0).~$

There has not yet been an occurrence of either $~n~$ consecutive wins or $~m~$ consecutive losses.  
Further, there has just been an occurrence of exactly $~j~$ consecutive wins, where $~j \in \{ ~1, ~2, ~\cdots, ~n-1\}.~$ 
This implies that either the $~(j+1)$-th previous trial was a loss, or there have only been $~j~$ trials, all of them wins. 
For $~j \in \{ ~1, ~2, ~\cdots, ~n-1 ~\}, ~$ I will let $~f(n,m,j,0)~$ denote the probability of winning if you are in this state.

There has not yet been an occurrence of either $~n~$ consecutive wins or $~m~$ consecutive losses.  
Further, there has just been an occurrence of exactly $~k~$ consecutive losses,
where $~k \in \{ ~1, ~2, ~\cdots, ~m-1\}.~$ 
This implies that either the $~(k+1)$-th previous trial was a win, or there have only been $~k~$ trials, all of them losses. 
For $~k \in \{ ~1, ~2, ~\cdots, ~n-1 ~\}, ~$ I will let $~f(n,m,0,k)~$ denote the probability of winning if you are in this state.



$\underline{\text{Recursive Equations}}$
Then
$$f(n,m,0,0) = [ ~a \times f(n,m,1,0) ~] + [ ~b \times f(n,m,0,1) ~]. \tag1 $$
For $~j \in \{ ~1, ~2, ~\cdots, ~n-2 ~\},~$
$$f(n,m,j,0) = [ ~a \times f(n,m,j+1,0) ~] + [ ~b \times f(n,m,0,1) ~].$$
Also,
$$f(n,m,n-1,0) = [ ~a \times 1 ~] + [ ~b \times f(n,m,0,1) ~].$$
Similarly,
For $~k \in \{ ~1, ~2, ~\cdots, ~m-2 ~\},~$
$$f(n,m,0,k) = [ ~a \times f(n,m,1,0) ~] + [ ~b \times f(n,m,0,k+1) ~].$$
Also,
$$f(n,m,0,m-1) = [ ~a \times f(n,m,1,0) ~] + [ ~b \times 0 ~].$$

$\underline{\text{Markov Chains}}$
My MathSE exposure suggests that the problem can be elegantly completed via something called markov chains, which I know nothing about.
My primitive alternative approach will be to eliminate each of the $~f(n,m,j,0) ~: j \geq 2~$ and $~f(n,m,0,k)~: ~k \geq 2~$ variables, by induction.  Then, I will be left with $~3~$ linear equations in the three unknowns, $~f(n,m,0,0), ~f(n,m,1,0), ~$ and $~f(n,m,0,1),~$ so I can then solve for $~f(n,m,0,0).$

$\underline{\text{Induction on} ~j}$
Hypothesis: 
For $~j \in \{ ~1, ~2, ~\cdots, ~n-1 ~\}, ~$
$$f(n,m,j,0) = a^{n-j} + [ ~f(n,m,0,1) \times b \times ( ~a^{n-1-j} + a^{n-2-j} + \cdots + 1 ~) ~].$$
By inspection, the hypothesis is true for $~j = n-1.$ 
So, assume that the hypothesis is true for $~j = J.$
Then,
$$f(n,m,J-1,0) = [ ~a \times f(n,m,J,0) ~] + [ ~b \times f(n,m,0,1) ~] $$
$$= a^{n-(J-1)} + [ ~f(n,m,0,1) \times b \times ( ~a^{n-1-<J-1>} + a^{n-2-<J-1>} + \cdots +  a + 1 ~) ~].$$
Therefore, the hypothesis has been proven by induction.
Therefore,
$$f(n,m,1,0) = a^{n-1} + [ ~b \times f(n,m,0,1) \times ( ~a^{n-2} + a^{n-3} + \cdots + 1 ~)  ~] $$
$$= a^{n-1} + \left[ ~b \times f(n,m,0,1) \times \frac{1 - a^{n-1}}{1 - a} ~\right] $$
$$= a^{n-1} + \left[ ~f(n,m,0,1) \times \left( ~1 - a^{n-1} ~\right) ~\right]. \tag2 $$

$\underline{\text{Induction on} ~k}$
Hypothesis: 
For $~k \in \{ ~1, ~2, ~\cdots, m-1 ~\} ~$
$$f(n,m,0,k) = f(n,m,1,0) \times a \times \left( ~1 + b + \cdots + b^{m-1-k} \right).$$
By inspection, the hypothesis is true for $~k = m-1.$ 
So, assume that the hypothesis is true for $~k = K.$
Then,
$$f(n,m,0,K-1) = [ ~a \times f(n,m,1,0) ~] + [ ~b \times f(n,m,0,K) ~]$$
$$= f(n,m,1,0) \times a \times \left( ~1 + b + b^2 + \cdots + b^{m-1 - <K-1>} ~\right).$$
Therefore, the hypothesis has been proven by induction.
Therefore,
$$f(n,m,0,1) = f(n,m,1,0) \times a \times \left( ~1 + b + \cdots + b^{m-2} \right)$$
$$= f(n,m,1,0) \times a \times \left( ~\frac{1 - b^{m-1}}{1 - b} \right)$$
$$= f(n,m,1,0) \times \left( ~1 - b^{m-1} \right). \tag3 $$

$\underline{\text{Problem Completion}}$
Repeating the equations in (1), (2), and (3) above:

$[E_1]:$
$f(n,m,0,0) = [ ~a \times f(n,m,1,0) ~] + [ ~b \times f(n,m,0,1) ~].$

$[E_2]:$
$f(n,m,1,0) = a^{n-1} + \left[ ~f(n,m,0,1) \times \left( ~1 - a^{n-1} ~\right) ~\right].$

$[E_3]:$
$f(n,m,0,1) = f(n,m,1,0) \times \left( ~1 - b^{m-1} \right).$


Combining $~[E_2]~$ and $~[E_3]~$ to solve for $~f(n,m,1,0)~$:
$$f(n,m,1,0) = a^{n-1} + \left[ ~f(n,m,1,0) \times \left( ~1 - b^{m-1} \right) \times \left( ~1 - a^{n-1} ~\right) ~\right] \implies $$
$$f(n,m,1,0) \times \left[ ~a^{n-1} + b^{m-1} - \left( ~a^{n-1} ~b^{m-1} ~\right) ~\right] = a^{n-1} \implies $$
$$f(n,m,1,0) = \frac{a^{n-1}}{ ~\left[ ~a^{n-1} + b^{m-1} - \left( ~a^{n-1} ~b^{m-1} ~\right) ~\right] ~}.$$
Combining $~[E_2]~$ and $~[E_3]~$ to solve for $~f(n,m,0,1)~$:
$$f(n,m,0,1) = \left\{ ~a^{n-1} + \left[ ~f(n,m,0,1) \times \left( ~1 - a^{n-1} ~\right) ~\right] ~\right\} \times \left( ~1 - b^{m-1} \right) \implies $$
$$f(n,m,0,1) \times \left[ ~a^{n-1} + b^{m-1} - \left( ~a^{n-1} b^{m-1} ~\right) ~\right] = a^{n-1} \times \left( ~1 - b^{m-1} ~\right) \implies $$
$$f(n,m,0,1) = \frac{a^{n-1} \times \left( ~1 - b^{m-1} ~\right)}{ ~\left[ ~a^{n-1} + b^{m-1} - \left( ~a^{n-1} b^{m-1} ~\right) ~\right] ~}.$$
Therefore, by $~[E_1]~$:
$$f(n,m,0,0) = \frac{a^n}{ ~\left[ ~a^{n-1} + b^{m-1} - \left( ~a^{n-1} ~b^{m-1} ~\right) ~\right] ~} $$
$$+ \frac{a^{n-1} \times b \times \left( ~1 - b^{m-1} ~\right)}{ ~\left[ ~a^{n-1} + b^{m-1} - \left( ~a^{n-1} b^{m-1} ~\right) ~\right] ~}$$
$$= \frac{ ~a^n + \left[ ~a^{n-1} \times b \times \left( ~1 - b^{m-1} ~\right) ~\right] ~}{ ~\left[ ~a^{n-1} + b^{m-1} - \left( ~a^{n-1} b^{m-1} ~\right) ~\right] ~}$$
$$= \frac{ ~a^{n-1} \times \left[ ~a + b - b^m ~\right] ~}{ ~\left[ ~a^{n-1} + b^{m-1} - \left( ~a^{n-1} b^{m-1} ~\right) ~\right] ~}$$
$$= \frac{ ~a^{n-1} \times \left[ ~1 - b^m ~\right] ~}{ ~\left[ ~a^{n-1} + b^{m-1} - \left( ~a^{n-1} b^{m-1} ~\right) ~\right] ~}.$$

Our answers are pretty much identical.  As you posted first I have deleted mine.

A short solution is as follows. Let $p$ (resp. $q$) denote the probability of $n$ consecutive successes before $m$ consecutive failures given that the first run was a success (resp. failure). If the first run was a success, we either have another run of $(n-1)$ successes and win, or we fail at some point before that and end up in the same situation as after the first failed run. The former happens with probability $a^{n-1}$, hence the latter happens with probability $1-a^{n-1}$. Therefore,
$$
p=a^{n-1}+(1-a^{n-1})q.
$$
A similar reasoning with success and failure excahnged gives $$1-q=b^{m-1}+(1-b^{m-1})(1-p),$$ or $q=(1-b^{m-1})p.$  Substituting into the first equation above gives
$$
p=\frac{a^{n-1}}{a^{n-1}+a^{m-1}-a^{n-1}a^{m-1}};\quad q=\frac{a^{n-1}(1-b^{m-1})}{a^{n-1}+a^{m-1}-a^{n-1}a^{m-1}}.
$$
The overall answer is of course $ap+bq$, which recovers Ross' answer if we recall that $a+b=1$.
As mentioned in another answer, ideologically, what we are computing above are  absorption probabilities of a Markov chain, but this connection is not actually strictly needed.
